# Part of Mesh turns white in Render Mode

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, modifiers

This is my first time using blender, and I am trying to create an animation for a phone.

When I am in object mode in material view, the image looks fine, but when rendering a frame (in cycles) part of the matte black is white instead. When I remove the subsurface modifier it looks fine, but I want to keep the modifier.

Any ideas what is causing this? I have included a screenshot of one area where this is happening but this isn't the only place.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

[image]

Comment: Subdivision surface modifier affects the material boundaries. The white part of the mesh on your render is the screen's material. You can apply the modifier and then reassign the materials, or you can use edge creasing on the screen's boundaries. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-crease

Comment: There could be many reasons for this, better to upload the .blend file and include the link in your question in order to have accurate answers. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Applying modifier and then reapplying materials did not work. Edge crease worked in some places but not others. I have added file to the post, the image textures obviously won't worked because there are a lot of external images I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be that you used the Glossy Shader in the material. This causes the world background to be reflected in some parts of the mesh.

[image: Material Nodes you used]

Comment: I don't think this is it. I tried using just a diffuse and had the same problem